# How does this where syntax works?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I was looking into this solution from GitHub for a problem asked in *Haskell from First Principles* book. Here is the code

```
data Nat =
    Zero
  | Succ Nat deriving (Eq, Show)

integerToNat :: Integer -> Maybe Nat
integerToNat i
  | i < 0  = Nothing
  | i == 0 = Just Zero
  | i > 0  = Just (Succ x) where (Just x) = integerToNat $ i-1
```

I'm confused at

> where (Just x) = integerToNat $ i-1

I thought I can only assign an expression to an identifier in `where`. But it looks like the `(Just x)` unpacks the value of the expression assigned and assigns `x` back to `(Succ x)`.

Can somebody explain why this works?

Comment: Why not? ;) you are basically correct, it kind of unpacks the rhs. This is the same pattern matching machinery that works for function definitions, like `natToInteger Zero = 0; natToInteger (Succ x) = 1 + natToInteger x`.

Comment: Keep in mind that, even if `where Just x = ...` defines `x` via pattern matching, this can be dangerous: when `x` is demanded, if the pattern is not matched (e.g. because the recursive call returns `Nothing`), a runtime error will be raised, crashing the whole program. Of course, here it can never happen, yet the burden is on the programmer to ensure that.

Answer (score 4):

The Haskell [*context free syntax*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-18000010.5), has an entry about the *right hand side (rhs)* of a function:

> rhs → `=` exp [`where` decls]
>           | gdrhs [`where`
>   decls]

So that mean we have to take a look to `decls` to get the `where` syntax. `decls` is a sequence of `decl`s:

> decls → { decl<sub>1</sub>; ...; decl<sub>n</sub> }

And a `decl` has again two possible rules:

> decl→ gendecl
>           | (funlhs | pat) rhs

So that means we can declare patterns (pat) in the left hand side of a `where` clause. Actually in a `where a = 1`, `a` is already a pattern so to speak. The pattern consists out of one variable. But constructors, alias operators, etc. are all acceptable at the left hand side of a `where` clause.

A pattern can be a variable, a generic constructor, a qualified constructor, a literatal, a wildcard, list pattern, tuple pattern, irrefutable pattern, etc. Then entire grammar for *patterns* can be found [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#dx17-180063). So in short it works like pattern matching in the head of the function.

Comment: Got it. It means I can write less since where supports constructor matching...Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @NirvinM: yes the `where` clause works like the pattern matching system in the head of a function works.